# Pulling a CSV file from website into QGIS with ability to automatically refresh?

Tags: qgis, csv

I am attempting to pull a CSV file from a website that is updated daily. I would like to have a process that can automatically perform the process and save daily as a new layer. The CSV file is related to tracking forest fires and has multiple attributes. The CSV download url is http://www.wildfire.alberta.ca/reports/activedd.csv. I attempted to use the a vrt driver to load the file into QGIS as a layer but I was unable to pull the attributes as well as the lat/long locations.

I am fairly new to QGIS.

Answer (score 4):

You can load the CSV file directly (or have ftp load the file to your local drive)
QGIS will detect the change and reload the data on the fly.

If you want it to change use the 'watch file'

[image]

result
[image]

use wget to get the csv (every minute,hour,day etc)
(task scheduler)

[image]

Comment: Do I utilize the "Add Delimited Layer" function to add the csv? If so, don't I have to have the csv saved locally first in which case the daily updates will not occur automatically?

Comment: loosely based from http://fulcrumapp.com/blog/live-data-visualization-in-qgis/ which version of qgis are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.8.2

Comment: you can use wget to retrieve the file (and replace the existing one ) updated post

Comment: Reggie so this is working for me using wget and using the watch option in qgis 'file:///C:/temp/activedd.csv?type=csv&skipEmptyFields=Yes&xField=fire_location_longitude&yField=fire_location_latitude&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=yes'