# In QGIS add new attribute table features from updated csv

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, csv, update

In QGIS I created a point layer from a csv using "add delimited text layer" (the comma icon). I set style and viewing scales the way I want for the layer. Since then the csv has been expanded with many new points. Is there a procedure for updating the attribute file with the new data?

Comment: Have you tried the "watch file" option in the add delimited text layer dialog as described in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148812/pulling-a-cvs-file-from-a-website-into-qgis-with-the-ability-to-automatically-re