# Automatically update and reclassify project layer from Excel data

Tags: qgis, python, excel

I have a project in Qgis that gets its data from a locally stored excel file (linked). Is there a way to automatically update the linked data? What is happening now is that when I change some rows in the excel file, I have to go back to the project "delete" and "classify" the selected data. I would like to see this automated. I have very few (none) experience with Qgis.

Comment: Is it an excel file or a csv?  If the layer is classified using the column attribute it should stay classified even if the rows change.   If you right click on the layer you can see the attribute table and that may help "visualize" what is happening.   From VIEW -> Panels -> Layer Styling you can select the column you want to Categorize with.  Look Here -> https://ibb.co/tDJrv9V

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you could give us a little more information about what you are doing. For example, plotting points in an Excel file on background mapping. Does the Excel file contain xy coordinates?

Comment: I got CSV file working with the 'watch file' https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148812/pulling-a-csv-file-from-website-into-qgis-with-ability-to-automatically-refresh

Comment: @nhopton: I got a layer that is linked with a shape file (Qgis ID - Coordinates) next I have another layer that is linked with the excel file (Qgis ID - Name). Through the Qgis ID I'm able to link Coordinate with Name.

Comment: @Cary H: I opened your link and this is exactly what I'm seeing in my layer that contains the shape file. If I change values in the column of the locally stored excel file, I automatically see changes in the layer in qgis that's connected to it, but the layer containing the shapefile doesn't refresh its data. In layer containing shapefile I go to: properties-symbology-delete all-classify

Comment: Can you do a hover over your Layer to determine where the layer source is coming from?  My example (Linked) I have 2 layers that are 2 completely separate shape files.  If you open the Properties - Information (Blue circle icon at the top ) and look at the file name.   Are you showing 2 layers with 2 seperate files?  https://ibb.co/7gbn3FD  -  https://ibb.co/1TyH8Q4.   Are you doing something like  Mapperz?