# Import CSV from online resource

Tags: qgis, csv, online

With QGIS it´s easy to load non-spatial CSV Data (and use it for joins).

[image]

This works fine as long the CSV resides on the local file system as [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148812/pulling-a-csv-file-from-website-into-qgis-with-ability-to-automatically-refresh) suggests. Is there some way to import a CSV from an online resource like https://example.com/myfile.csv without first downloading it? (Maybe by use of some plugin or Python snippet?)

Comment: Not sure about an existing plugin in Q but you may write your own referencing this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371043/use-python-requests-to-download-csv

Comment: nice thanks! so what is missing then is how to create a non-spatial layer with the return. will ask google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in QGIS.

QGIS is able to open remote resources using [GDAL Virtual File Systems](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html#gdal_virtual_file_systems_vsicurl) `/vsicurl/`

#### Add layer

Use **Add Vector Layer**, and write the remote URL of the CSV file with the prefix `/vsicurl/`. The complete filename should be something like: `/vsicurl/http://localhost/~jgr/sinaletica.csv`

Using your example, it should be: `/vsicurl/https://example.com/myfile.csv`

[image: add remote file using vsicurl]

#### Convert table to layer

If you just need the table for joins, you don't need this additional step.

If the table has some kind of X and Y columns, you can convert the table to a layer with geometries.

Use **Create points layer from table** to create a layer from the table.

[image: use create points layer from table algorithm]

Comment: You don't need the `vsicurl` (tested in QGIS 3).  Just the full url in the file tab or the HTTP(s) protocol tab.

Comment: @jgrocha wow, thanks a lot – this sounds really useful. My csv does not have any spatial information (x+y) but should only be joined with an existing attribute table I will try if this works with adding a textfile as layer without geometries as well.

Comment: @jgrocha nice the first suggested way works for csv without coordintaes. great thanks!

Comment: @jgrocha Loading a csv from remote by use of vsicurl works nicely but fails if it´s a dbf. By chance any idea how to get this working?