# Read a .csv file from a URL with an API call in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, csv, api, url

How do I read a .csv file from a URL with an API call, including key, in QGIS 3?

I've tried creating a .vrt file as outlined [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/109084)

I've tried the solutions presented [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/316719)

If I'm doing everything correctly, then the differences between these examples and my case are that my URL is https and that my URL has an API call following the .csv extension.

eg:
https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.csv?fuel_type=HY&state=CA&api_key=G3tUr0wNk33&format=csv

The .vrt file I assembled:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTLayer name="test">
    <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="0">/vsicurl/https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.csv?fuel_type=HY&state=CA&api_key=G3tUr0wNk33&format=csv</SrcDataSource>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude"/>
</OGRVRTLayer></OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Comment: The solution though in the questions referenced mention http and https, so that's probably not the issue.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the VRT you created to do this?

Comment: @nmtoken I have edited the question to show the VRT file

Comment: One thing that you must correct is to use XML escaped special characters in the VRT file. Thus this is at least more correct as data source `<SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="0">/vsicurl/https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.csv?fuel_type=HY&amp;state=CA&amp;api_key=G3tUr0wNk33&amp;format=csv</SrcDataSource>`. Unfortunately that did not make the vrt to work for me. Continue from this and use ogrinfo for testing `ogrinfo apitest.vrt --debug on`.